# Macro that populates values in specific column according to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask for a help. I’m looking for a macro which would do such action:

I have a column called Comment and five other columns which should be populated according to the Comment column. If in Comment column there is a message “duplicate” I would like to mark in column called Duplicate 1 if not it should be 0. Also in this case it happens that two values can indicate 1 to be populated – i.e. Left - Replacement Found and Left - No Replacement. For both of those values It should be 1 populated in the Left Column, for others 0.

I modified macro which I have for Vlookup and I was able to get if function but only for 1 specific logical test (in this example "Left - Replacement found). I would need to have more than 1 logical test. So in this case I would like to have Left - Replacement Found and Left - No Replacement marked as 1 and the rest as 0.

```
Sub Testing_if_function()
Dim FormulaCol As Long
Dim LookupCol As Long
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim TotalCols As Long
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Data").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To TotalCols
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "Test" Then FormulaCol = i
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "Comment" Then LookupCol = i
Next

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""Left - Replacement Found"",1,0)"
Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
With Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity for you to learn some VBA. Alternatively, this can all be done with worksheet formulas. If you are not familiar with worksheet formulas, and for someone who has no/limited knowledge of VBA, this would be a better course of action.

Comment: For such things I do this manually but every day I receive couple of spread sheets where all steps of data cleansing takes ages. I made myself or with help from stack overflow people almost everything what I need to fully automate this process and concentrate learning VBA. I know I should start with the IF function but setting this up in a macro seems to be too complicated for me.

Comment: I was able to reach almost what I want. The only thing which is missing is the multiple logical test to have 2 values. Does anyone know how should I amend the code to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem. So if anyone will need similar macro, here is the code:

```
Sub Testing_if_function()
Dim FormulaCol As Long
Dim LookupCol As Long
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim TotalCols As Long
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Data").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To TotalCols
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "Test" Then FormulaCol = i
    If Cells(1, i).Value = "Comment" Then LookupCol = i
Next

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""Left - Replacement Found"", 1, IF(RC[-2]=""Left - No Replacement"", 1, 0 ))"
Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
With Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```